# Android WebView in ViewPager not scrolling vertically when in Landscape Orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling, vertical-scroll

I have a ViewPager that shows 3 fragments. One of the fragments has got a WebView and I am experiencing 2 issues:

1) It seems that the size of the ViewPager (height) is bigger than the screen size. (see following image)

[image]

2) Scrolling is working correctly when switching from a tab to another on, while it is not working vertically when the APP is landscape orientation.
When in landscape mode I can scroll up the page touching the toolbar and the TabLayout but I cannot scroll up touching the WebView.
What I am trying to do is to scroll up touching the WebView and not only the Tab or Toolbar.How can I do that?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.it.rocks4x4.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!--
      <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="REGISTRA"
          android:elevation="6dp"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="center"/>-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/msg_inizia_registrare"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/black"
     tools:context="com.it.rocks4x4.activities.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webviewbussola"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: try this  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" add it into your manifest instde the activity in which you are having issues for orientation and check if this is working or not

Comment: Unless you are compiling against Froyo (API 8), please stop using FILL_PARENT to specify layout_width and layout_height. Use MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: I tried both suggestions but no good result.
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" is removing the scroll

Comment: change you coordinator layout to relative layout or scroll view and see if its working or not.

Comment: check this out it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602124/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-a-webview

Comment: not working all the received suggestions